# Should this variable be declared statically or dynamically?

Tags: c++, winapi

As I'm practicing Win32 API (C++), I've stumbled across one dilemma.
In the code provided below, `WindowProcedure` callback function is being shown, and one of the actions that I'm handling, specifically `FILE_CHANGE_TITLE` case.

```
case FILE_CHANGE_TITLE: {
    wchar_t* text = new wchar_t[100];
    GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
    SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
    delete[] text;
    break;
}
```

In this case scope, after detecting that the action was identified as `FILE_CHANGE_TITLE`, I want to perform some action - specifically get the text from one `HWND` object (`hEdit`) and put it into another `HWND` object (`hWnd`).

For that purpose, I've extracted the text into a dynamically allocated `wchar_t` pointer array that after usage will be freed in the memory. Is this a good approach or should I consider statically declaring the wchar_t array? Some explanation would mean a lot.

Full callback procedure code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case FILE_CHANGE_TITLE: {
            wchar_t* text = new wchar_t[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
            SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
            delete[] text;
            break;
        }
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT: {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }
        case FILE_MENU_OPEN: {
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"New file pressed", L"New file", MB_OKCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        BuildMenu(hWnd);
        BuildControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"The window has been closed and the app will stop running.", L"Program closed!", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You *could* make this a static array. Although you would usually call `GetWindowTextLength()` first, and then allocate a dynamically sized array. The only thing you should definitely not be doing: Calling `new` and `delete`. A `std::vector` does all that for you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I agree, vector could work. Is there any specific reason why we should not use `new` and `delete` in such scenario? Is it an anti-pattern or something performance-related?

Comment: for only 100*2  bytes - better allocate memory in stack, as local variable. simply as `wchar_t text[100];` only better not direct inside `WindowProcedure` but in separate function: `case FILE_CHANGE_TITLE: OnTitleChange(hWnd);`  and `void OnTitleChange(HWND hWnd)
{
  wchar_t text[100];
  GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, _countof(text));
  ...
}`

Comment: There is literally no reason to use `delete` in C++, and outside of placement-`new` or `new(std::nothrow)` no reason to use `new` in C++. This makes code easier to maintain and easier to keep correct. Performance-wise, there is no difference at all.

Comment: I think the correct terminology is heap vs stack allocation, or dynamic array vs fixed-sized array on stack. You are using dynamic array with constant size, you could replace that with fixed array. Fixed array is easier but it can deplete limited stack memory, if you over do it. `std::vector` is a common solution in this case, also you don't have to guess the size.

Comment: If we go with the static/stack approach, would that mean that the N*2 bytes reserved will be permanently use the memory during the runtime of the program? Would there be any way to not use that chunk of memory, no matter how small it is, when we're not utilizing the function that is using that memory?

Comment: all alocated in stack is temporary and auto "free" when function return. also in stack possible allocate and variable size memory by using [`_alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170). or you can use [`_malloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=msvc-170). for ui only 100-200 chars usually enough

Comment: Auto (stack) data is only "allocated" in a particular scope (code surrounded by `{ ... }`).